# The graph on the Activity tab of my Profile page miscalculates reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

The screenshot shows the miscalculation of the reputation graph on my new profile page:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

The graph shows that I've earned 7,929 reputation, But actually, I've just got 7,866 reputation (at the time of writing).

I don't know what is causing the problem. Maybe it is because I have an active bounty [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c)?

Comment: If I log out, then [I can see 8,006 reputation even though I have 7,877 now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/74a9k.jpg).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254558/my-reputation-graph-on-math-se-shows-me-as-having-the-wrong-reputation

Comment: There are a few things the mini graph doesn't currently take account of. This is already on my list.

Comment: I know this is 2 years old but it is something I have noticed myself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user was removed, and with them any reputation gained, the calculations for the graph did not have data to account for the split between posts that such a user voted on that were deleted and those that were not.

The effect was that some votes got added twice for this calculation and not once.

We have now added accounting for these and are recalculating reputation for those effected.

Comment: I know this is old, but it still happens. I currently have 17413 reputation but the graph shows the max reputation as 17513. Minor issue though, just wanted to let you know :-)